# reading data from xml file to table

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, oracle10g

how to read data from xml file to table

Comment: I think he means to a database table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787354/convert-to-xml-file-should-be-load-into-table Please avoid duplicating your question .. do add some relevant info and proceed with the question

Comment: @V4Vendetta:Good comment

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" ecoding="UTF-8"?>
<entert>
<row uniq_id="2" TIN="30850104385" ack_no="0" schedule="A" ITEM="423" totalturnover="423" rate="43" tax_payable="182"/>
<row uniq_id="4" TIN="30140303771" ack_no="0" schedule="A" ITEM="65" totalturnover="656" rate="56" tax_payable="367"/>
</entert>
/?>                                                                  This is my xml code and i want to read these two rows in table which is present in database. i am very new at c#,asp.net progrmming so please sugges me answer in step by step method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly read an xml file to a datatable using DataTable.ReadXml http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml.aspx
Then do your db commit  with the data.

Answer (score 1):

It's so easy, just call [DataTable.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml.aspx)